# Visual Studio C# Console doesn't display top lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, console-application

I am learning the programming basics in C# and am studying the use of "for" function.

When working on an exercise I realised there's something wrong with my console - it seems as if it did not display top 6 rows.

I.e. with such a code:

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,-3}", j);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

My console spits out only smth like this:

[[image: Console message back is two rows, one with eight number sevens, the second with eight number eights][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQewV.png)

Dear masterminds, wwyd?

Comment: I'd increase the buffer size of the console ?

Comment: Not reproductible under Windows 10-x64 VS2017 .NET Framework 4.7.2: I see `1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8\r\n
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8` with the code provided and `int size = 8;`.

Comment: Thanks Caius, I know it is a dumb question, but it's really my very beginning - how?

Comment: "how to use scrolling in console window on OS of my choice" is not really on-topic on SO... Side note: despite idea that "Think Different" is interesting you may want to start writing loops `(i = 0; i < size; i++)` as everyone else...

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the buffer size for the console as @Caius Jard suggested you need to press the right mouse button on the top console bar.

[image]

Press Properties

[image]

Change settings until you will see it will work for you. In the screenshot, you can find Windows default settings that I'm using.

You might need to re-run your program to notice some changes.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted to help others that see that this issue was resolved